# Looping Projection in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, modelbuilder, wgs84, utm

I've got a global DEM raster dataset in WGS84 and need to project this to all WGS84 UTM Zones. So after that I should have 120 raster, one in each Zone.

Is there a possibility to automate this process with the ArcMap ModelBuilder?
I tried the "for" iterator, but I can't choose the epsg as iterating value.

---

Then I need to run the flow length tool on all those rasters and then reproject the resulting 120 flow length rasters again into WGS84.

Do you have any idea for an efficient way to create a ModelBuilder path for that?

Comment: Do you have a list of all epsg codes? Or know where it can be found?

Comment: Its the epsg 32601-32660 for the northern hemisphere and the epsg 32701-32760 for the southern hemisphere

Comment: You can find them on http://spatialreference.org/ . And it is the epsg 4326 for the WGS84.

Comment: @BERA (Im relatively new to this community so sorry for not linking you in the answer above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use Python for this. The code can be executed in the Python window of ArcGIS.

```py
import arcpy, os

dem = r'C:\folder\dem.tif' #Change to match your DEM. Can also be a raster in a database
out_folder = r'C:\outfolder' #And this. If it is a database, remove .tif below

#List all UTM epsgs:
epsgs = range(32601,32661) + range(32701,32761)

#Project raster for each:
for epsg in epsgs:
    print 'Reprojecting to epsg: ',epsg
    arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(in_raster=dem, out_raster=os.path.join(out_folder,'Reprojected_epsg_{0}.tif'.format(epsg)), 
                                  out_coor_system=arcpy.SpatialReference(epsg))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @BERA . I try to learn python and arc py but I'm a beginner. But so this is a great cance to learn something new.

Comment: I tried to execute the script but I get the error message "The operation was attempted on an empty geometry"

Comment: @David Probably because your DEM is not covering the area of the UTM zone you are trying to Project it to. I just tried the code and it works when i Project it to a zone Close to the raster but fail with a zone far away from the raster.

Comment: Yes youre right. I wanted to try it out wit a little testing area, it was my fault. I've got one additional question: how do I have to change the script to implement it into the ModelBuilder like this?: http://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-scripts-within-a-model.htm

Comment: @David try following the instructions in the link. If you get stuck post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Even in this case, it's better to use Python. But you can use the ModelBuilder to do that after get a list of all the reference systems that you want to project to.

To get the list in a text file for all the reference systems, you can use arcpy as Bera mentioned [@BERA] and as follows:

```
#import modules
import arcpy

#set workspace
path = r"C:\reflist.txt"
file = open(path, 'w')
reference1 = range(32601,32661)
reference2 = range(32701,32761)
refList = reference1+reference2
print len(refList)
print refList
for ref in refList:
    print ref
    file.write(str(ref) + "\n")
file.close()
print "Script completed"
```

Then import the list into ArcMap and export is as a table.

[image]

Then in a new Model, make it something like this:

[image]

For the (Iterate Field Values), choose your reflist table, ref field and define data type as coordinate system:

[image]

For the (Project Raster) tool, don't forget to define output name as (e.g Raster_%Value%.tif)

[image]

And then you can go further with other tools and processing.

Comment: @BERA I tried it with (project tool) for a vector layer and it works. I couldn't try it for the raster because the smallest raster I have around 1 GB on the size and I don't have enough space or resources for 120 rasters.

Comment: Thank you very much @User2009 this is really helpful. I will try it very soon.

Comment: I've followed your steps and tried to run the toolchain but I get the Error 000622 for invalid input at the coordinate system.

Comment: @David I retried checking it and it works properly. Did you define where you got this error? in the (project raster) or in another tool?

Comment: I get this Error in the Project raster tool. Also it and the following tools are stll white. The arc Map help says "not-ready-to-run (elements are white), it means that one or more input variables are invalid" (Source: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/validating-a-model.htm ) @User2009

Comment: Another problem occured with my toolchain ( I created a new thread for that https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278040/arc-modelbuilder-is-looping-the-wrong-tools )

Comment: I am not sure why you get this error