# Using ModelBuilder to Iterate Row Selection with ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, iterator, for-loop

I have a model that does a lot of linear calculations, then eventually runs into an ITERATE ROW SELECTION tool.  I only want the iterator to cycle through the tools downstream of itself, but instead it runs the entire model for every iteration.

Since the other calculations take several hours to perform and will not change between iterations, is there any way to have the model only loop through the processes downstream of the iterate tool?

Basically I want to initialize a for loop, run only part of the model in the loop, then close the loop, but I can't figure out how to do that.  [image: Excerpt from model showing iterate row selection and processes immediately leading to it, which do not need to be included in the loop.]

Comment: Welcome to GIS-SE. There are a number of other similar questions on the site that may already have useful answers to your question, such as my answer at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/278046/22780  I would suggest reviewing some of them and then updating the question or posting a new question with more specific/targeted question(s) with where specifically you're stuck, if you still need assistance.

Comment: Golden rule with model builder is that a model with an iterator will execute as many times as it loops. This means EVERYTHING will run x number of times. You need to place your iterator in its own model with attached downstream processing then that becomes a model in your master model. You need to be reading help on "sub-models" or search forums and review their Q&A to understand what sub-models are all about.