# ModelBuilder: Error 999999 "Failed to copy raster dataset"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, modelbuilder, loop, error-999999

I want to run the "Project Raster" tool in the ModelBuilder of ArcMap but I get the "ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Failed to copy raster dataset."
and I have no reason why.

Input is a simple Tiff raster and the projection is looped like described here:
[Looping Projection in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277429/looping-projection-in-arcgis-modelbuilder/277457#277457)

Comment: Does it work when if you Project it manually once?

Comment: @BERA It runs successfully when I choose a single projection and let the output name as "DEM_%Value%.tif" but I can't find the output data in the output folder. When I change the output to a normal data name it works perfectly.

Comment: Just to try and exclude an inline variable problem, could you try DEM_%n%.tif as the output name in the iterative model?

Comment: @RJJoling Then I get "ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
The operation was attempted on an empty geometry."

Answer (score 4):

Following the link you provided it is clear from the screenshots (always good to include those!) for the answer you have ticked as correct that you are projecting your raster into a file geodatabase.

Thus a raster name such as DEM_%value%.tif is invalid as you cannot store tifs in a file geodatabase. Simply edit the tool output to not be a file geodatabase but a folder.

Comment: But the tool want a raster dataset as output and no workspace. And how else should the tool know how to call the output raster files?

Comment: What you say makes no sense, don't direct the output to a geodatabase, direct it to a folder if you want your output format to be tiffs.